# Check if the pass-in parameter is in the array object

Tags: javascript

I want to check if my pass-in parameter is in the object array or not. Somehow the if statement in the check function always execute and return (even if the pass-in parameter is in the array).

```
// member object 
function member(lname, fname, mname){
   return {
      lname: lname,  // object property
      fname: fname,
      mname: mname
   };
}

var user = [
    member('lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename'),
    member('last', 'first', 'mname'),
    member('l', 'f', 'm'),
    member('ll', 'ff', 'mm')
];

function find(u){
    for(var i = 0; i < user.length; i++){
        if(u === user[i].lname){
            return user[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function check(u) {
    var r = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < user.length; i++){
        if(find(u).lname !== user[i].lname){
            return "not a user";
        }else if(find(u).lname === user[i].lname){
            return "it's a user";
        }
    }   
}
console.log(check("last"));
```

Comment: A `return` statement exits the function immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You've coded that `for` loop in the "check" function so that it returns, one way or the other, on the first iteration. That is, there's no way to get through the loop more than once because both the `if` and the `else` end with a `return`.

You don't need that anyway. If the "find" function returns non-null, then you know it must be a user, and there's no need to do any more work:

```
function check(u) {
    var r = 0;
    return find(u) !== null ? "it's a user" : "not a user";
}
```